# Unit testing angular4 component - test gives error when component function is called and component property is used

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-components

Below is my component's HTML:

list-comments.component.html

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row listCommentsContainer">
      <h2>Best Of Books</h2>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8" *ngFor="let commentData of commentsData; let i = index">
          <ol style="list-style: none;">
          <li class="listComments">

            <div  style="display: block">
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
              <a class="avatar">

                <img style="" src="{{commentData.profile_image}}">
              </a>
            </div>
            <a class="commentPostByUserName">
              <span class="commentPostByUserName" style="">{{commentData.first_name}}</span>
            </a>
              <div class="commentTime">{{commentData.time_stamp}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="commentTextDisplay">{{commentData.object}}</div>

            <br>

            <!-- Click Reply -->
            <div class="addReplyContainer" #commentData.id>
              <a  class="addReplyLink"  (click)="showReplyTextArea($event, commentData.id)">Reply</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Add Reply -->
            <div [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" class="addReplyContainer replyTextAreaContainer" style="display: none" >
              <textarea (keyup)="keyUpCommentTextarea($event, reply, commentData.id)" [(ngModel)]="reply" style="width:100%"
                        class="replyText commentText addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
              <button [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" disabled class="btn btn-success addCommentBtn" (click)="addReply($event, commentData.target_id)">Add</button>
            </div>
            <!-- -----Add Reply end------ -->

            <!-- List Replies -->
            <div class="replies col-lg-8 col-sm-8" *ngFor="let reply of commentData.comment">
              <ol style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="listComments listReplies">

                  <div  style="display: block">
                    <div style="display:inline-block;">
                      <a class="avatar">

                        <img style="" src="{{reply.profile_image}}">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="commentPostByUserName">
                      <span class="commentPostByUserName" style="">{{reply.first_name}}</span>
                    </a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="commentTextDisplay replyTextDisplay">{{reply.object}}</div>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </div>
            <!-- -------list reply end-------- -->

          </li>
          </ol>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Add Comment-->
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="addCommentContainer col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

          <textarea (keyup)="keyUpCommentTextarea($event, comment)"
                    [(ngModel)]="comment" class="commentText form-control"
                    placeholder="Add Comment">
          </textarea>
        <button  disabled (click)="addComment($event)" class="btn addCommentBtn btn-success">Add</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Add Comment end-->
</div>
```

This is my spec file:

list-comments.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ListCommentsComponent } from './list-comments.component';
import {DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from  "@angular/core";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// require('zone.js');
// let chai = require('chai') ,
// spies = require('chai-spies');
// chai.use(spies);


describe('ListCommentsComponent', () => {
  let component: ListCommentsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListCommentsComponent>;
  let debugElement:DebugElement;
  let htmlElement:HTMLElement;



  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [ ListCommentsComponent ],
     // providers:[HttpClientModule, HttpClient]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListCommentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();


  });



  fit('should be disabled', () => {

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.addCommentBtn'));
    htmlElement =debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(htmlElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('disabled');
  });

});
```

In my test above I just want to check If I button has property disabled.

Let me know If this is not right way to check button's disabled property on page load.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit**

After searching for few hours I have figure out that my problem of accessing debugElement attribute can be solved using jQuery.
So instead of using debugElement I used $ and it worked completely fine.

I have modified my spec file to:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ListCommentsComponent } from './list-comments.component';
import {DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from  "@angular/core";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import * as $ from 'jquery';
// require('zone.js');
// let chai = require('chai') ,
// spies = require('chai-spies');
// chai.use(spies);


describe('ListCommentsComponent', () => {
  let component: ListCommentsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListCommentsComponent>;
  let debugElement:DebugElement;
  let htmlElement:HTMLElement;




  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [ ListCommentsComponent ],
     // providers:[HttpClientModule, HttpClient]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListCommentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();


  });



  fit('should not be disabled when we add message', () => {

    component.keyUpCommentTextarea("hello", null);


      let addCommentBtn = $('button.addCommentBtn').attr('disabled');

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.addCommentBtn'));

    expect(addCommentBtn).toEqual(undefined);
  });


  fit('should  be disabled when we do not add message', () => {

    component.keyUpCommentTextarea("", null);


    let addCommentBtn = $('button.addCommentBtn').attr('disabled');



    expect(addCommentBtn).toEqual('disabled');
  });


  fit('should match array',  () => {

    let commentsJson = {
      root_id:"1",
      target_id: 1,
      text: "hi",
      comment_posted_by:"Jack",
      comment_posted_by_image:"/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
      profile_image:"/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
      first_name : "john"
    };

    component.addComment();

    expect(commentsJson).toEqual(component.commentObj);

  });



  it('should be string',  () => {

    component.addComment();
    expect(component.comment).toBe('string');

  });


});
```

In my last test I called a *function* **addComment** and it involves **this.comment** and **this.commentObj** properties of **list-comment component** when code reaches a line where this.comment is accessed I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: the link for workaround is broken. Also, have you tried doing `this.debugElement.attributes.disabled` (see docs for `DebugElement`) https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement#attributes

Comment: Thanks @John for reference. I have solved that problem by help of jquery. Can you help me with an edit I made in my Question if you have time? I will be very grateful.

Comment: I am not familiar with testing in `Angular` (yet), so I am not sure I am able to help you out at this moment. At least you have a jquery solution that works until someone is able to help out, or you figure it out yourself.